# Batch Script: Scan through the files in a directory and check the month part of the last modified date

Tags: batch-file

I am searching everywhere and I would like to ask if this is feasible in a batch script. This is what I did so far.

1. I moved some files from a source to a destination location. I only choose file older than 30 days ago. My batch file is scheduled to run once everyday.
2. Once in the destination location, **is it possible for me to check (through batch file) the month part of the last modified date? So that I can include it in the appropriate zip file?**

For example:

Todays Date is July 30, will process files dated June 30 and will put/update them in the zip 201406.zip

Todays Date is July 31, will process files dated July 1 and will put them in the new zip 201407.zip

Thanks in advance guys, I keep on looking a solution for this.

Comment: Questions describing your requirements and asking someone to write the code for you, explain how to write the code, provide examples or references, or tell you if it's "feasible" are off-topic. Please identify a specific problem or question about programming. Include attempted solutions, an explanation of how the results differ from the desired results, and the full text of any error messages you receive. Please read this advice on asking good questions: [[ask]], [[Writing the perfect question](http://goo.gl/UeT2tS)].

Comment: What I did so far is to create an archiving batch script which zips all 30 days ago and the name of the zip file depends on the month of the current date. But I have no control of the contents of the files inside since months differes in the number of days